# is there a way to control goalkeeper in head to head seasons match?

Tags: fifa-12

We can control the goalkeeper in kick-off match by pressing the `back` button (<|) but it doesn't work in head to head seasons match, so I am wondering if there is another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no there is not. EA has created the "Head to Head Seasons" (H2H-S) game mode with many restrictions in order to keep the matches "fair" (the more correct term would be "uniform"). Therefore, when playing a H2H-S match, there are many game-play options that are "greyed out" or disabled for this reason.

As another example, EA does not allow the player to switch back to legacy defending (the old type of defending from previous FIFA games) in H2H-S.

I guess EA has deemed that controlling the keeper is not a fair option to exercise in a match (which I agree with honestly- the keepers become ridiculously overpowered when you control them).

Hope this helps!